# Download.file function does not seem to work

Tags: r

I want to extract some data for a .csv online into R. So therefore Im doing this (Ive already created a dir called "data")

```
fileUrl <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.csv", method="curl")
```

It gives the my following error however:

```
 Warning messages:
 1: running command 'curl  "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-     2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"  -o "./data/cameras.csv"' had status    127 
 2: In download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.csv", method  = "curl") download had nonzero exit status
```

And if I remove the `method= "curl"` I get

```
Error in download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.csv") : 
unsupported URL scheme
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

Comment: Your code works well for me. `method = "curl"` is necessary if you have Mac OS and most likely (but I am not suer) for Windows too if the address is `https` so do not remove it.

Comment: Try `setInternet2(TRUE)` if you're on windows.

Comment: Do you have a line break or other spacing character (like tab) within the URI? If so, put everything on one line without blank spaces.

Comment: Thanks@BrandonBertelsen this helps. Working fine now. What exactly is setInternet2(TRUE) doing?

Comment: @user3706202: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/setInternet2

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.  Changing method = "curl" to method = "auto" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Note the http instead of https, the code below will work:

```
fileUrl <- "http://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/cameras.csv",method="curl")
```